# Install Django on python 3.8 in Windows

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to install `django` on `python 3.8` by command `pip install django` but I got an error:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django (from versions: none)
```

what can I do?

Comment: have you googled your error?  There are lots of questions already out there with this exact same error message

Comment: if you are on windows I would suggest you use conda to install django in virtual environment here is a link on setting venv on windows using conda https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html

Answer (score 1):

i guess you are using linux distro, maybe you should use `pip3` or `pip3.8` (for `python 3`) instead of `pip` (for `python 2`)

refer to this topic https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#requirements-for-installing-packages

> Due to the way most Linux distributions are handling the Python 3 migration, Linux users using the system Python without creating a virtual environment first should replace the python command in this tutorial with python3 and the python -m pip command with python3 -m pip --user. Do not run any of the commands in this tutorial with sudo: if you get a permissions error, come back to the section on creating virtual environments, set one up, and then continue with the tutorial as written.

```
pip3 --version
pip3 install django  # it will install the last version of django
```

or

```
python3 --version
python3 -m pip --version
python3 -m pip install django  # it will install the last version of django
```